# VBA excel trying to create a macro that imports data from file then if the data is equal to a specific value put one cell into a sheet on the new file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a spreadsheet that will import data from another file, scan the file for certain values in column D and then paste specific cells (not the whole row) into the first row that has a blank cell in column F in the new spreadsheet.

This is my updated code now

```
Sub GetAmazonData()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Adspend As Workbook
Dim A As String
Dim Amazon As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

Set Adspend = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Specify data export file

A = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Processed")
Set Amazon = Application.Workbooks.Open(A)


counter = 2

' While Not Amazon.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & counter) = ""

     If Amazon.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & counter) = "B01GB3HZ34" Then


        Set targetSheet = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom")
        Set sourceSheet = Amazon.Worksheets(1)

        LastRow = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom").Cells(Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row


        targetSheet.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("D" & counter).Value

     Else

        LastRow = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom").Cells(Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        targetSheet.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("D4").Value

    End If

  '   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Active

' Wend
Amazon.Close


End Sub
```

I expect this bit of code to paste what is in the imported file's first sheet cell D1 into the sheet called DirtyDom in cell F1 since 1 is the first cell blank in column F.

I get the error Object variable or With block variable not set.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't say which line you get the error on but your last row looks odd. Try lastRow = Adspend.worksheets("DirtyDom").Cells(Adspend.worksheets("DirtyDom").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I believe it's my while loop that is breaking now.  I changed it to     If Amazon.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & counter) = "B01GB3HZ34" Then
        Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
        Set targetSheet = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom")
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = Amazon.Worksheets(1)
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom").Cells(Adspend.Worksheets("Dir??tyDom").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        targetSheet.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("D" & counter).Value

Comment: Do you still get the same error message. What line is highlighted when you hit 'debug'?

Comment: I commented down below on updated code.  It breaks when I try to use the LastRow as the row for a target

Comment: You should update your question rather than using the answer box. you've put the last row assignment back to your original. Put all your dims at the top, then have your set commands as the first statements. Don't hide them in the middle of your code. It'll be much easier to debug. You probably need to check your lastrow is being assigned what you think it should be. Do a debug.print statement & check it has the right value. Don't forget lastrow+1 will be your first empty row.

Comment: From my above code the LastRow prints out 1

Comment: I actually just figured it out.  I needed to add a         Set targetSheet = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom")
        Set sourceSheet = Amazon.Worksheets(1) in the else!

Thank you!

Comment: Okay. I was just posting a code piece and missed this. Good. Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it also puts your loop back in and resets your screen updating and alerts - untested.

```
Sub GetAmazonData()

Dim Adspend As Workbook
Dim Amazon As Workbook
Dim Targetsheet As Worksheet
Dim Amazonsheet As Worksheet
Dim Amazonfilename As String
Dim lastAmazonrow As Long
Dim lastTargetrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set Adspend = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Targetsheet = Adspend.Worksheets("DirtyDom")

    'Specify data export file
    Amazonfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Processed")
    Set Amazon = Application.Workbooks.Open(Amazonfilename)
    Set Amazonsheet = Amazon.Worksheets(1)

    lastAmazonrow = Amazonsheet.Cells(Amazonsheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastTargetrow = Targetsheet.Cells(Targetsheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For counter = 1 To lastAmazonrow
        If Amazonsheet.Range("D" & counter) = "B01GB3HZ34" Then
            Targetsheet.Range("F" & lastTargetrow).Value = Amazonsheet.Range("D" & counter).Value
        Else
            Targetsheet.Range("F" & lastTargetrow).Value = Amazonsheet.Range("D4").Value
        End If

        lastTargetrow = lastTargetrow + 1
    Next i
    Amazon.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```